# Objeto não encontrado - Error 404 em htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Num site que desenvolvo, ao escrever um link que não exista, dá-me erro conforme a seguinte imagem.

[image: Objeto não encontrado - Error 404]

Pretendo que, **ao escrever um link que realmente não exista**, mostrar uma página de error 404 sem que o link se altere, em vez de mostrar esta mensagem de aviso de "Objeto não encontrado".

Se for possível criar isto no htaccess, para mim seria uma das hipóteses.

Answer (score 2):

Para criar o redirecionamento, deve-se utilizar a diretiva ErrorDocument, adicione em seu `.htaccess`, como pode observar no exemplo:

```
## Redirecionar em caso de erros ##
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: Comentou com ErrorDocument 400, mas é error 404.
Editei, e testei e sim, esta é a solução.

Comment: você pode incluir mais linhas dessas, para outros erro como 500, 502, etc